# Match files in directory with glob and regex

Tags: php, glob

I had a problem with glob in php.
First I'm create thumbs dynamically and file named as "thumb_width_heigth_filename.ext"
Then i had to delete all created thumbs with "filename.ext" its not complicated. I use:

```
$filename = "name.jpg";
glob(realpath($path)."/thumb_[0-9]*_[0-9]*_$filename")
```

its work fine for me, but.
if I have files like:

```
name.jpg
thumb_20_20_name.jpg
thumb_200_200_name.jpg
```

and I'm also have files like:

```
QQ_name.jpg (because system automatically add random 2 symbols if file already exist in folder)
thumb_20_20_QQ_name.jpg
```

Then I want to delete name.jpg and cleanup thumbs I use my code, and got all files matching include QQ_name

I know howto delete files, help me, please, exlude files like *QQ_name.jpg when I'm search 
    thumb_[0-9]*_[0-9]*_name.jpg

Please help find out.

Answer (score 0):

This finds every file, that has $filename at the end of the $filename.
With array_map() and unlink() you can delete all these files very simple.

```
array_map('unlink', glob('path/*'.$filename));
```

This will delete

```
name.jpg
thumb_20_20_name.jpg
thumb_200_200_name.jpg
QQ_name.jpg
thumb_20_20_QQ_name.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm know howto delete files, i had to exclude files "QQ_name.jpg,
thumb_20_20_QQ_name.jpg" when im try to delete only "name.jpg" and thumbs for name.jpg